# How to search for a method name in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

The `Cmd + O` only allow you to search for method in the current opened file, are there any easy method to search for method in your project?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, You can see `Search For` box, select Method. In `Scope`, select Enclosing projects.

Comment: What about Linux and mac ?

Comment: What if I want to search by method's qualified name? Is there a way or I need to go to the class first?

Comment: You can't say Ctrl-H will bring "Search For" Ctrl-H and the Java Search tab will show "Search For". Most people use File Search. It doesn't work either except for the simplest cases.

Answer (score 2):

Use "Java Search" in the search menu or move the caret on the function name in the source and press Ctrl+Shift+G (-> search for reference in Workspace).

[EDIT] If you don't know in which class the function is, then use the text search (which is called "File search"). Enter the name in the search field and then limit the search to "*.java" files.

Comment: You can even add a set of projects where the file will do the search, if you don't select it, it would search in your whole workspace.

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>to search for declarations of the method your cursor is currently sitting on, as opposed to the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> mentioned by user1071979 which shows all references to method.  kshen mentioned <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> which will give you greatest flexibility - though giving you a dialog box to fill out to go further.

Answer (score -1):

**1.** I always prefer <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to find methods, variable etc...........

**2.** This also gives the functionality to replace one or all the names with the one you want to...

**3.** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> is also very helpful for **finding method, variables, package**,etc....

Answer (score -1):

- <kbd>F3</kbd> - open declaration
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> - open additional search dialog
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> -search references in workspace